# ENS Domains and new receive addresses for privacy

Tags: ens, privacy, private, eth-domain

Currently I use a new receive addresses every time I receive ETH - Ledger Live creates new receive addresses by default when an address has been 'used' as this is good practice in terms of privacy.

I'm looking at getting an ENS domain to make it easier for people to transfer ETH to me. What are the privacy implications when using ENS domains and are there any best practices? Currently I'm assuming the typical use case is to point the domain at a single receive address and share the domain so privacy would be sacrificed for usability. Even if I were to update the receive address after every transaction, I believe the addresses would still be linked.

Answer (score 1):

There is no behind the scenes difference between an ENS domain and an Ethereum address. Each ENS domain points to a single Ethereum address in the same way that a URL points to an IP address (when you go to google.com, you are actually being sent to xxx.xx.xx.xxx, but this is handled by default the scenes).

Because of this, there should be no additional safety concerns when using ENS. With that said, the method you described in the first paragraph of recieving ETH to different addresses would be a little more cumbersome. If you wanted someone to be able to send ETH to yourname.ens, but have it go to a different address each time, you would have to make a transaction (spend money) to change where the ENS domain is pointing each time.

Comment: Would it not be possible to see the history of addresses for a domain therefore making it pointless to update the address?

Comment: You are correct. I was simply offering an explanation as to how it would work. Ethereum doesn't use HD wallets like Bitcoin, so receiving multiple TX to different addresses will not result in all the coins going to a single address.